# Azure media service for shared app

Tags: c#, azure, service, xamarin

I've been trying to use the Azure Media Service for a shared native app in Visual Studio 2015.. But whenever i try to install the windowazure.mediaservices.extensions package, i get an error because apparently it isn't cross platform compatible on all three OS. However i can add another nuget Microsoft.windowsAzure.Managment.MediaServices - but it does not give me the same namespace as the one i get with the media services samples i downloaded earlier.

Does anyone have experince with the two nugets - and can tell me the difference? And if so - could provide me with a link to a sample that uses the last mentioned nuget.

An additional remark/question - i cannot get it to work on xamarin.forms either - not on shared or portable project.